# Gradle : variable reassignment inside doFirst

Tags: gradle

I am trying to use the "doFirst" way of calling a method in gradle. my code looks like

```
task nightlyBuild(type:MavenTask) {
ext.list = 'this should change'
doFirst {
    ext.list = getList()
            println ext.list
}

    mvnCmdLine "clean deploy -am -amd ${ext.list}"
}
```

mvnCmdLine is a method in a class that calls maven for me (depending on the OS)

output looks like this

```
-pl com.blah.foo:bar
mvn clean deploy -am -amd this should change
```

My problem is that when I run this, the println ext.list prints what im expecting to see, but when the maven command executes it drops in "this should change"

It seems that the doFirst has no control of reassigning a new value to the variable, outside of itself. Is there some special type of return? or am I not creating global variables?

Comment: `mvnCmdLine "clean deploy -am -amd ${ext.list}"` seems to be in the wrong place. It needs to go into `doFirst` or something.

Comment: UPDATE : I figured this out a few weeks ago, updating for posterity. What I realized is that you can't run doFirst during the configuration phase, it is a execution phase only operation. So what I was seeing is the doFirst happening after my task that was a configure task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out now. The phases are very important to gradle.

So configuration happens before execution, and before doFirst and doLast. So the logic should either look like

```
task nightlyBuild(type:MavenTask) {
    ext.list = 'this should change'
    doFirst {
        ext.list = getList()
            println ext.list
    }

    doLast {
        mvnCmdLine "clean deploy -am -amd ${ext.list}"
    }
}
```

Basicly the mvnCmdLine was being run during the configuration phase and wasn't run after the ext.list was changed.